# Hasura: How to establish relationship to existing record (many to many) at insert time?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Hasura: How to establish relationship to existing record (many to many) at insert time?

I have two tables: product and category that are linked to each other in a many to many relationship based on an id column in each table and an intermediary table product_category.

I can insert records directly into postgres for both tables and link them with product_category and this works great in Hasura for queries so I know I have set things up properly.

What I want to be able to do is insert a new product and knowing the id of a category (or categories) I want to establish the relationship at insert time. Preferably without a seperate call

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html#insert-an-object-along-with-its-related-objects-through-relationships

The documentation only covers inserting both the object and related objects at the same time but what if the other one already exists?

I have tried what I would expect to work (linking this product to category with id 1):

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_product_one(
    object: {
      name: "Champion", 
      category: {data: {id: 1}}
    }) {
    id
  }
}
```

But that throws:

"Not-NULL violation. null value in column \"product_id\" violates not-null constraint"

How can I insert this new product and link it to one or more categories? Preferably all in one statement but even an example of retrieving the generated id and an update mutation would be not ideal, but non-the-less a solution.

Update: As a sanity check I've recreated the product and category tables as a minimal, basic example and tried both my query and the upsert conflict method xadm suggested.

The data and relations I've added some screenshots of here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaVrh.jpg

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_testproduct_one(
    object: {
      name: "Champion", 
      category: {
          data: {id: 1},
          on_conflict: { constraint: primarykeything , update_columns: [id] }
    }
    }) {
    id
  }
}
```

The error is similar: "Not-NULL violation. null value in column \"testcategory_id\" violates not-null constraint"

Note: primarykeything is the primary key on the bridge table consisting of the two ids.

Comment: IMHO this is described in docs you provided - you need to provide entire nested data (category, read it earlier) and use `on_conflict`

Comment: @xadm so you're saying you try insert a duplicate of the nested data and on_conflict handles updating instead? I did try it but haven't managed to make it behave yet. Basically the same error is thrown when trying to use it.

```    on_conflict: {
        constraint: product_pkey ,
        update_columns: [id]
    }
```

Comment: I don't use it, I read this docs and IMHO it should work that way ... search on issues and eventually open one providing minimal example - looks like reverse relation fails?

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables?  It's hard to know what the issue is without knowing the structure.

Comment: @LeonardoAlves added some screenshots from Hasura of the structure and update based on what xadm added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a many to many relationship, you have a join table in between them.  From what I can see in the screenshot you posted the id for the category in your category relationship is called `testcategory_id` and not `id`.

```js
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_testproduct_one(
    object: {
      name: "Champion", 
      category: {
          data: {testcategory_id: 1}
    }
    }) {
    id
  }
}
```

For it to work the id in the table testproduct_testcategory has to be auto-incremented

Comment: Thank you! That works! I can also understand why it works. Now that I've seen it working. The relationship name is category but that's essentially a "view" into the bridging table.

Not immediately intuitive but  I do get it now.